# newsletter delivery

Tags: support, email, newsletter

I subscribe to about 15 newsletters from the Stack Exchange network, with about 2 to 3 newsletters each day.

I have not received any since this Friday, March 14th, i.e. for about a week now. Has there been an outage or a change?

Comment: I received the Stack Overflow newsletter last night. Seems fine on my end.

Comment: What can I do to troubleshoot? Change mail ID?

Comment: You've probably already tried this, but have you checked your spam folder? Maybe you accidentally marked one as spam and now they're all directing there. (I know I've done that with legit emails before.)

Comment: Go [here](http://stackexchange.com/users/13750/vaibhav-garg?tab=subscriptions), try to unsubscribe then subscribe again to all of them. Any luck?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm your subscription and that they are being sent.  The best I can tell you after that is that it's in the mail.

Comment: Still can't receive them, tried unsubscribing and resubscribing, and didn't even get the welcome mail.